# AWS EC2 multi instance exit with a single IP Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, webhooks, elastic-ip

I have an AWS infrastructure as follow:

- EC2-WS01
- EC2-WS02
- Load balancer

[image]

These machines run the same code. In front of these machines is there a Load Balancer that distribute the load. So the clients point to the load balancer that forward the requests. One of the services of my app is a webhook service that send to an external server, protected by a firewall, some information every 15 minutes. We had to setup the firewall accepting the request from the two EC2 IP Address. I want to know if is possible make sure that regardless of the instances I have, when I make a request, it is always made by the same ip

Is possible to do that with an Elastic IP or what else?

Comment: I cannot understand your question because the keywords you used are mixed up and do not describe your situation accurately.

Comment: Omk I try to explain better.

Comment: NAT. Add a NAT with an Elastic  IP (EIP) and route your web server outbound requests through the NAT. Whitelist the EIP on the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your architecture would need to be:

- Load Balancer in a public subnet
- Amazon EC2 instances in private subnet(s)
- A NAT Gateway or NAT Instance in a public subnet, with an Elastic IP address
- A Route Table on the private subnet(s) that sends Internet-bound traffic via the NAT Gateway/NAT Instance

The traffic from the Amazon EC2 instances will "come from" the public Elastic IP address associated with the NAT Gateway/NAT Instance.